# Android MapView Class Not Found

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-mapview

When trying to run the mapview in the emulator or on the device, the activity crashes.  I feel this may be due to an import issue with the required libraries.  The error will show a class not found exception.  Please let me know if you need more information.  I have also been following this tutorial: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435

Activity:

```
package com.klinetel.countydentistfinder;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class ClinicMapActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    MapView m;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clinic_map);


    }





}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.ClinicListingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_listing"
            android:parentActivityName="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.ClinicMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_clinic_map"
            android:parentActivityName="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.ClinicListingActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.klinetel.countydentistfinder.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=""/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

[image]

Comment: I have an API key, I just left it blank for security.

Comment: have you referenced the google play services library project?

Comment: I referenced the google-play-services.jar in the project.

Comment: From the properties area, then by adding an external jar.

Comment: you should not add the jar instead reference the library project in your map project. check my post

Comment: It says this app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone.  I can post a picture is needed.

Comment: yes and you need to download them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add it as a external jar file.

You should reference the library project in your android map project.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace (folder where your android map project is). The library project can be found under the following path.

```
     <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

Import the library project to your eclipse

**Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the     workspace  import the library project**. You can check if it is library project. Right click on the library project. Goto properties. Click Android on the left panel. You will see Is Library checked.

Right click on your android project.  Goto properties. Choose Android on the left panel. Click on Add and browse the library project. Select the same. Click ok and apply

[image]

Also make sure you have enabled google maps for android in the google api console

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not fixing the map problem.  It says this app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone.

Comment: what are the errors this is the right way. i am sure about it. however you might be doing something wrong else where. check if there are errors in your resources folders. check if you have R.java generated.

Comment: one question why google-play service are required here ? just curious !

Comment: @RachitMishra have you not checked the docs. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start. check the first step in the docs.  The Google Maps Android API is distributed as part of this SDK.

Comment: @Klinetel you will need google play services on your device to run your project testing it on device or phone?

Comment: @Klinetel glad i could help and the blog by emiladz is good. if you have any problems you can ask on so and emil will answer http://stackoverflow.com/users/1561247/emil-adz

Comment: Well, I am too learning, and as I knew, and I learned play-services are to connect to map-servers, and in my case same app, with the answer i just wrote, runs good, I get an authentication error, and I get same error as specified in this problem if I change it to, SupportMapFragment

Comment: @RachitMishra post a new question with relevant details if i can i will surely anwer

Comment: @RachitMishra you must ask a clear question with relevant details of wht works what does not work if you show some research effort no one will downvote. but if you say i did this and it does not work they will downvote.