# Android Map issue

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple app that uses map.after doing all coding map in not visible in output.only a zoomin and zzomout button is visible

below is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<permission
android:name="com.example.map1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>   
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBoSLfTOWdAny2vrtwMx6lFTuWdoyANJlQ"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

below is xml file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

I am testing my app on htc 1x.

here is logcat

```
08-27 00:24:10.419: I/(3812): Loading GLESv1_CM implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra_impl
08-27 00:24:12.284: I/Google Maps Android API(3812): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
08-27 00:24:27.739: E/Google Maps Android API(3812): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Comment: Take a look at the LogCat, it should give you an error. Can you put that in here?

Comment: have you added google-play-services library ?

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet? If it is, check your date and time on it and make sure it's accurate (sounds odd, but it can cause this error).

Comment: Let's not be posting the actual keys or anything that resembles a key anywhere.  Please make it something like.   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My google map api key"/>

Comment: @jprofitt I don't think it would compile without adding the google play library.  Still could be an issue how the library was added.

Comment: I have downloaded google play services via sdk

Answer (score 0):

**It seems you have not added the play services to your project**

You should reference the library project in your android map project.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Refer to this answer for more help on how to add play-service lib to your project

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450128/826657

Answer (score 0):

Are you using camera??, I get this error when use the camera and google map at the same FragmentActivity.

If i comment the camera code no gets errors, but when i activate this code, google the map is white and log says this:

03-03 13:42:39.721: E/SurfaceTexture(7327): [unnamed-7327-0] updateTexImage: error binding external texture image 0xafc9ec8a (slot 1): 0x502

Only on my HTC ONE X (nvidia tegra)